# Could not execute method for android:onClick - retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to retrieve data from a web api.
I use retrofit, I made the interface for it, but when I try to use it, I have an exception declare

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.wind.wind, PID: 2388
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at com.wind.wind.sign_in.onClicksignin(sign_in.java:57)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code:

```
package com.wind.wind;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.wind.wind.data_user.User;
import com.wind.wind.remote.windAPI;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class sign_in extends AppCompatActivity {

//EditText fields
EditText login_;
EditText password_;

//String containers
private String login;
private String password;
private windchatAPI api;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    login_ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    password_ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}

public void onClicksignin(View v)
{
    login = login_.getText().toString();
    password = password_.getText().toString();
    windchatAPI.Factory.getInstance().getUser().enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response)
        {
            Log.e("login success", response.body().getToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("login failed", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

I think the problem is that windchatAPI is not declare, but I don't know how to do it.
Can someone help me ?

windAPI is my interface for hold informations:

```
public interface windAPI
{
  @GET("user/register")
  Call<User> getUser();
  String URL = "my_url";

  class Factory
  {
    private static windAPI service;
    public static windAPI getInstance()
    {
        if (service == NULL)
        {
            //creating the base URL from winchat api
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).baseUrl(URL).build();
            service = retrofit.create(windAPI.class);
            return service;
        }
        else
            return service;
    }
  }
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_sign_in"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.wind.wind.sign_in"
android:background="#fffc00">

<TextView
    android:text="Login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="Enter your login"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
    android:hint="Enter your password" />

<TextView
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:text="Log in"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:onClick="onClicksignin" />
```

When I delete in the java code the line windAPI.Factory... it works...

EDIT: manifest added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wind.wind">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<!-- Used for retrofit api -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Login_page">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".wind_sent" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".sign_in" />
    <activity android:name=".register_activity"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Where are you linking that onClick method to the button? In an XML? With butterknife? can we see the xml

Comment: what is on the sign_in.java:57?

Comment: This is generally cause when findViewById() is not able to identify correct resource from your xml file. Please paste your xml and complete code of your java activity file.

Comment: XML updated and java too

Comment: You're not by any chance missing the closing tag of `RelativeLayout` .? Just checking was it a mistake in copying or ?

Comment: Yes sorry, it's a mistake in copying

Answer (score 0):

Please check 2 things:

1. Have you declared your activity in the manifest? I can see you have a

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.wind.wind.sign_in.onClicksignin(sign_in.java:57)`

2. Is your `RelativeLayout` closed in the `XML` file?

Comment: The relativelayout is closed in the code, I just forget it when I copied here. The activity sign_in is added in the manifest, but not the interface

Answer (score 0):

in your sign_in class do this

```
public class sign_in extends AppCompatActivity implement OnClickListener {

//EditText fields
EditText login_;
EditText password_;

//String containers
private String login;
private String password;
private windchatAPI api;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    login_ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    password_ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(this)
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    login = login_.getText().toString();
    password = password_.getText().toString();
    windchatAPI.Factory.getInstance().getUser().enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response)
        {
            Log.e("login success", response.body().getToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("login failed", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

and remove the onClick From the xml